# how do convert color code in as3

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, colors

My Goal is to  add the color for text by dynamically.

```
var tf:TextField = new TextField();
tf.text ="jkg"
tf.textColor = chatData.user;
listChat.addChild(tf);
```

> Here my chatData.user is 16777215 this format.But i  need chatData.user (0xFF0000) this format.how do i convert the color code?

Comment: What is the problem with the code you listed? What color is `16777215` supposed to be?

Comment: i need hexadecimal format but here chatdata.user is decimal format.Thats my problem

Comment: `textColor` is just a `uint`. Decimal or hex it's the same number. I could set it to `255` or `0xff` or `0x0000ff` or `(1<<8)-1`, and it would all be blue. As long as its a `uint` and not a `string` then its ok. Have you *tried* your code?

Comment: var hexString = ("0x"+number.toString(16));
tf.textColor = hexString;  here number is chatdata.user.Nothing displayed..

Comment: Am new in as3,kindly Can you Explain me in detail with code?

Comment: What data type is `chatData.user`? Is it a `string` or a `uint`?

Comment: i used chatdata.user as shared object

Comment: As others have stated, you don't need to convert the format.

Have you tried running your program at all? If you have, you should find that it works the way it should. If you are experiencing an error, please post it.

Comment: Finally i got answer.Thankyou sir

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var number:uint = chatData.user;
tf.textColor = number
```

Try this

Answer (score 1):

Check out the global function: parseInt(String[, radix])

It treats strings starting with 0x as hexadecimal ones. If there is no 0x; you can specify 16 for the radix parameter.

```
tf.textColor = parseInt(chatData.user);
tf.textColor = parseInt(chatData.user, 16);
```

Comment: Here dynamically i passed the color value(chatdata.user).This code is working tf.textColor = parseInt(chatData.user, 16); But it displays always same color

Answer (score 0):

It is very unclear what exactly your problem is/what you are trying to do.

But first, the hex representation of the decimal number 16777215<sub>10</sub> is FFFFFF<sub>16</sub>. Which is white... Not red (which would be FF0000<sub>16</sub>)

A `uint` is just a unsigned interger. It can be represented bases.

16<sub>10</sub> = 20<sub>8</sub> = 10000<sub>2</sub> = 10<sub>16</sub> = G<sub>17</sub>

Those are all the same integer, just different ways of showing them, but to most programming languages its the same thing. In flash you represent literal hexidecimal numbers using the `0x` notation. In ActionScript's cousin JavaScript, you can create a octal literal by prepending it with a zero (that seriously throws some people off some times `010==8`)

But back to what you are asking. I tested it out real quick, and the `textColor` setter will coalesce a string into uint if you give it a string.

```
        var tf:TextField = new TextField();
        tf.text = "Test";

        var color;
        color = 0xFF0000; // Red
        color = 16711680; // Red
        color = "16711680"; // Red
        color = "0xFF0000"; // Red

        tf.textColor = color;
        this.addChild(tf);
```

Those are all acceptable "reds", but really `.textColor` wants a `uint`, so the first two are the most valid. But `0xFF0000 == 16711680`. They aren't 'different' numbers... They are the same number, just different ways of expressing them.

So, I don't understand what your problem is? Your code should work, and do exactly what you've told it to do...

Answer (score 0):

Easy. Just parse the string into a uint.

```
var txtColor:uint=uint(chatData.user);
tf.textColor=txtColor;
```

Comment: This is obviously supposing that chatData.user is a valid number